# Angular directive window offset watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code:

```
.directive('sidenav', function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/side-nav.html',
            transclude: true,
            link: function($scope, element) {
                $scope.sidenavClass = "fixed";
                setInterval(function() {
                    console.log($window.pageYOffset);
                },1000);
                $scope.$watch(function() {
                    return $window.pageYOffset;
                }, function() {
                    console.log($window.pageYOffset);
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Interval console log show me different value when I scroll page, but watch is not working, why ?

Comment: Having a jsfiddle or plunkr will go a long way in helping us help you.

Comment: use ng-inspector chrome plugin to see what is really in scope ! don't trust console.log result with angular scope

Comment: Here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/k0QWTKCHQ9YVD0kgOb9F?p=preview , why when I scroll page watch dont work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just bind to the scrolling event of the window. Use apply since the event takes place outside of angular's digest cycle.

```
 angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
   console.log('scroll')
   $scope.$apply(function() {
     console.log(e.pageYOffset)
   });
});
```